# Android async httpclient: how to intercept authentication failures in one place?

Tags: android, asynchttpclient

I have the following mental model that for my android app, all authentication failures should be handled in a single place and the login screen should interrupt and be flashed on top of the view stack to allow the user to reauthenticate.

Not sure how to do this with AsyncHTTPClient.

I do not want to keep handling the 401 and 404 requests for every single GET and POST request that I make.  Sounds like a lot of repeated code.  So for google and CNN, for example, if I am not authenticated, I don't want to repeat the code to handle the 401 not authenticated code for both CNN and google because it's the same exact code.

Thank you!

```
 AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
 client.get("http://www.google.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
          System.out.println(response);
     }
     @Override
     public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable
 error)
 {
          error.printStackTrace(System.out);if 401, TELL USER he has to log in again

     }
 });

 AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
 client.get("http://www.cnn.com", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
          System.out.println(response);
     }
     @Override
     public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody, Throwable
 error)
 {
          error.printStackTrace(System.out);if 401, TELL USER he has to log in again

     }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

create your own subclass for `AsyncHttpResponseHandler` and implement the `onFailure` alone; Add all your failure handling logic in there.

Use this subclass for your `client.get` instead of `AsyncHttpResponseHandler`, just implementing the `onSuccess`.

```
    client.get("http://www.cnn.com", new MyAsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            System.out.println(response);
        }
        // onFailure handled by common code in MyAsyncHttpResponseHandler
     }
```